# Upload video to Facebook with Facebook graph API in twig

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twig

I'm running in to a issue regarding the Facebook Graph API. I'm trying to upload  video to my own wall using Twig. I managed to post a text message on the wall and now i want to place a video as well.

I'm doing the following:

```
{% set facebook = api.OAuth_ClientV2({
token_endpoint     : 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/oauth/access_token',
authorize_endpoint : 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth',
client_id          : '1478250628907658',
client_secret      : '29d6d80891e6dc2d0444796d9298d037'
}) %}
```

With this i'm creating a call to the facebook graph:

```
{# POST A VIDEO #}
{# {% set post = facebook.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me/videos?
source=***path_to_video****&access_token=***access_token****') %}
{{post|pre}} #}
```

But it will always give me the same error:

```
stdClass Object
(
[error] => stdClass Object
    (
        [message] => There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again.
        [type] => OAuthException
        [code] => 390
        [error_subcode] => 1363030
        [is_transient] => 1
        [error_user_title] => Video Upload Time Out
        [error_user_msg] => Your video upload timed out before it could be completed. This is probably because of a slow network connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large. Please try again.
        [fbtrace_id] => Eg7jLbvKsky
    )

)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: what's the size of your video ?

Comment: @sheplu: The size of the video is 20MB

Comment: ok so it's not about the size. if you try with a really small video (1 or 2s) do you have the same error ?

Comment: @sheplu yes. I'm still investigating it. Can it be something with the video_file_chunk parameter?

Comment: (What’s this got to do with Twig? That’s a templating language ... and apart from the fact that business logic should rather not be handled in the templates, you are using stuff like `api.OAuth_ClientV2` here - I doubt that is somehow part of twig? You should rather tag this with whatever system that component actually belongs to.)

Comment: Not much. the api.OAth_ClientV2 is something that we build ourselfs. That's working for sure. It's about the latest part .post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me/videos?
source=***path_to_video****&access_token=***access_token****')